# Can someone break down part of this Powershell script and explain what it does and how it works?

Tags: powershell

The Script:

```
$uninstall32 = gci "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" | foreach { gp $_.PSPath } | ? { $_ -match "Dell SupportAssist" } | select UninstallString

$uninstall64 = gci "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" | foreach { gp $_.PSPath } | ? { $_ -match "Dell SupportAssist" } | select UninstallString
if ($uninstall64) {
    $uninstall64 = $uninstall64.UninstallString -Replace "msiexec.exe","" -Replace "/I","" -Replace "/X",""
    $uninstall64 = $uninstall64.Trim()
    Write "Uninstalling..."
    start-process "msiexec.exe" -arg "/X $uninstall64 /quiet" -Wait
}
if ($uninstall32) {
    $uninstall32 = $uninstall32.UninstallString -Replace "msiexec.exe","" -Replace "/I","" -Replace "/X",""
    $uninstall32 = $uninstall32.Trim()
    Write "Uninstalling..."
    start-process "msiexec.exe" -arg "/X $uninstall32 /quiet" -Wait
}
```

I understand that this part is looking for GUID in the registry for a display name that matches Dell SupportAssist.

```
$uninstall32 = gci "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" | foreach { gp $_.PSPath } | ? { $_ -match "Dell SupportAssist" } | select UninstallString
$uninstall64 = gci "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" | foreach { gp $_.PSPath } | ? { $_ -match "Dell SupportAssist" } | select UninstallString
```

Can anyone explain the rest, mainly the -replace and -arg commands?

Comment: What do you think `-Replace` with two string parameters does? it looks for the first string and replaces it with the second string.

Comment: That's my point! -replace "msiexec.exe" .. Then replaces it with what? 

I have almost 0 Powershell skills so please bear with me if I'm asking what may seem like an obvious question to you

Comment: It replaces it with nothing (an empty string), meaning that it removes it altogether. Try it in your favourite text editor (which really should be VS Code)

Comment: @TomJ123 While we are willing to help, SO is not a replacement for working your way through a tutorial to get familiar with the language you're using. Please do that first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-replace` commands are stripping out all the executable arguments from the uninstall string then storing what's left.

It then runs the msiexec executable using the arguments specified in the -arg string (/X switch, the uninstall string from previously and the /quiet switch)

If you'd formatted the script properly (which I've done for you) it would have been much simpler to see how it's working

Comment: Literally my second post here, forgive me for the formatting!

Comment: I'm just not understanding why the replace command is there when the uninstall string is fine the Registry to use.  The UninstallString is MsiExec.exe /X{GUID} already.  

If you take that out though the script doesn't work!

And what links $uninstall64 to the -arg ?

Comment: (1) Presumably because the author wanted to remove the possiblity of running the /I switch
(2) Also because it can be tricky to just supply the full uninstallstring to Start-Process due to the way PS parses the string

Comment: Well that is for you to work out. We can only tell you what it does. You are the one with context around who wrote the script, when it is run, what it's meant to do etc.

Answer (score 0):

Note that get-package and uninstall-package can do the same thing more easily.  Oh, this is the same question, lol.